# Custom UI on Auth0

Tags: ios, authentication, social-networking, auth0

I need your help about auth0 social login. I have following ios code

```
- (IBAction)linkedin:(id)sender {

A0Lock *lock = [MyApplication sharedInstance].lock;
A0APIClient *client = [lock apiClient];
A0APIClientAuthenticationSuccess success = ^(A0UserProfile *profile, A0Token *token) {
    NSLog(@"We did it!. Logged in with Auth0.");
};
A0APIClientError failure = ^(NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Oops something went wrong: %@", error);
};
A0AuthParameters *params = [A0AuthParameters newDefaultParams];
params[A0ParameterConnection] = @"linkedin"; // Or your configured DB connection
[client authenticateWithSocialConnectionName:@"linkedin"credentials:@"token" parameters:nil success:success failure:failure];
```

My aim is simple, i try to create social login connection via using auth0. In the quickstart documentation of auth0 there is a sample which is using controller, and i also add custom connections.

```
 - (IBAction)signUp:(id)sender { 
A0Lock *lock = [[MyApplication sharedInstance] lock];
A0LockViewController *controller = [lock newLockViewController];
controller.connections=@[@"facebook", @"linkedin"];
controller.useWebView=YES;
controller.onAuthenticationBlock = ^(A0UserProfile *profile, A0Token       *token) {
    // Do something with token & profile. e.g.: save them.
    // And dismiss the ViewController
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];}}
```

But i cant use this because i need custom UI, i want to do this without controller. Can you please help me, what i m doing wrong in "authenticateWithSocialConnectionName" part. Thank you very much.